# javascript no working in <ons-template> - onsen ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

I want use JavaScript in many pages but it working only inside `<ons-navigator>` tag and don't working inside `<ons-template>`.
You can see my live example [jsfiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/memohmtl/jkuLswmw/) and give me solution please.
In the example when I scroll down I want show `px` position but its working only inside `<ons-navigator>`. How can I use JavaScript in `<ons-template>`?

Note: If you have another framework like onsen and working JavaScript in the cached page please write in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is actually a bit different - it's just that your selector `menu__menu` doesn't match anything. Just add an id to the page which you want to listen for scroll events like

```
<ons-page id="myPage">
```

and then use

```
var content = document.querySelector('#myPage .page__content');
```

and you will be fine :)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56adgqkq/)

Note: your side menu logic seems to be creating a new page after you switch the pages from there - if you want to execute some code each time when a page is initialized you may want to take a look at the `init` event - each page fires it when it becomes attached to dom. [Docs](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-page.html#events-summary)

Comment: for v1 the event is called `pageinit` btw